# Conditional $first in mongodb aggregation

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am trying to figure out if I can somehow combine $first and $ifnull or $cond in a mongodb aggregation method.
Assuming the following documents:

```
{ "_id" : 1, "item" : "box" , "code" : null }
{ "_id" : 2, "item" : "box" , "code" : "abcde" }
{ "_id" : 3, "item" : "box" , "code" : "abcde" }
{ "_id" : 4, "item" : "box" , "code" : null }
```

I then run the following aggregation method to group documents together:

```
db.items.aggregate([{
    $group : {
        _id : '$item',
        code :  { $first : '$code' }
    } 
}])
```

My aggregation result is:

```
{ "result" : [ { "_id" : "box", "code" : null } ], "ok" : 1 }
```

I would like to know if there is a way to combine the $first operand with $ifnull or $cond in order to get the code field which is not null. So my result would look like this:

```
{ "result" : [ { "_id" : "box", "code" : 'abcde' } ], "ok" : 1 }
```

Cheers,

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not in the way you want this to happen there isn't. You seem to be looking for a "conditional" way to evaluate [**`$first`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first/) and this just does not happen. All [**`$ifNull`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/ifNull/) can offer you is that where the field does not actually "exist" or otherwise evaluates to `null` then an "alternate" value is returned.

But you don't want this, and all it seems you basically want is to simply "filter" the possible results via a [**`$match`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) statement first:

```js
db.items.aggregate([
    { "$match": { "code": { "$ne": null } } },
    { "$group": { 
        "_id": "$item",
        "code": { "$first": "$code" }
    }}
])
```

But really, in your case and also unless you specifically need a "sort order" to come to the result, with a singular field you are better off just using [**`$max`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/max/) as an operator, even if a `$match` stage does actually "still" optimize this by excluding any documents that actually "should not be" part of the desired result:

```js
db.items.aggregate([
    { "$group": { 
        "_id": "$item",
        "code": { "$max": "$code" }
    }}
])
```

So `$match` and `$max` in the `$group` is probably what you really want in this case. The `$first` operator usually only makes sense when you want multiple fields from the document as a result and then only usually after a `$sort` operation unless your documents expect a "natural" sort order as they appear on disk ( and we mean that exactly, things can move around ).

So consider what you actually want to do and implement accordingly.

Comment: using the $max operand solved it for me. The aggregation method considers a value to be greater than null, apparently. Thank you for this.